# Will I be able to reenter the United States from Mexico using CBX if I don't have my passport card, yet?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, passports, us-citizens, borders

Will I be able to reenter the United States from Mexico using CBX if I don't have my passport card, yet? I have dual citizenship and am leaving to Mexico soon. Will I be able to use other documentation ie id card, social, copy of citizenship, passport receipt? Pls help.